# Spring Boot List of Object Bean Validation

Tags: spring-boot, validation, bean-validation

I have a Bean,

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public final class PersonRequest {

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("nameList")
    private List<Person> nameList;

   

}
```

and Person POJO,

```
@Data
    public class Sensor {

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("name")
    @Min(1)
    private String name;

}
```

I am sending JSON request and added `@Valid` in my controller. I am sending request as below,

```
{
    "nameList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Alex"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i send request without `id` and `name` not validating.  I tried using `@Valid private List<Person> nameList;` also but no luck. I use Spring boot 2.3.2.

**UPDATED:**

when i add one more attribute, this also say bad request when i pass date in request.

```
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("startTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", iso = 
                              DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @Valid
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
```

Comment: With `String` is more recommended to use `@NotBlank` instead of `@NotNull`.

Comment: thanks Seldo! Agreed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Valid` annotation in your controller triggers the validation of the `PersonRequest` object, passed as request body. To validate also the `Person` objects contained in `PersonRequest`, you need to annotate that field with `@Valid` too.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public final class PersonRequest {

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("nameList")
    @Valid
    private List<Person> nameList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, and when i add one more attribute ```@NotNull
    @JsonProperty("startTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @Valid
    private LocalDateTimestartTime;``` this also say bad request when i pass in request.

Comment: Unfortunately not with one parameter, it says bad request when i pass valid JSON.

Comment: Thomas you're correct, it was problem with my conflict in library. Thank you!